# Google Maps Gadget Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm not sure of the specific day, but on our company site, the Google Maps Driving Directions Gadget no longer functions, i.e. it is no longer accepting input and autoexpanding the directions.  This is the standard gadget found at http://maps.google.com/help/maps/gadgets/directions/.  I was just curious if anyone else is experiencing this issue, or is there a known conflict with jQuery or any other popular scripts?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue that is not only related to your site. We had the directions widget on a test server and it used to run fine. Last week I noticed it would not expand in IE and FF anymore, Chrome however is working fine.

I did some searching around on the net and there are other people having the same issues:

[Google support page](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=7a869782ff56cbd2&hl=en)

[Another Google support page](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=46d6355ef0fa9000&hl=en)

So this seems to be an issue with the Google code and we need to wait for them to fix it.